# How to set an icon to exe in visual studio 2017 using c++ win32 api by LoadIcon

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I want to set the icon by `wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(SOMETHING))` where wcex is the WNDCLASSX struct object for opening the main window. I am not sure about what is `SOMETHING` in `MAKEINTRESOURCE(SOMETHING)`.

I have loaded a .ico file by resource view in visual studio and I have a .rc file and the resource.h but don't know what to do with them.

After adding the .ico file the icon only appears in list of file explorer for the exe but not in taskbar or the exe window.

I am completely new to the winapi

Comment: `SOMETHING` is the the ID of that icon which you have imported in your resource script. For example `#define MY_ICON 10000`, `MY_ICON` should be the argument to `MAKEINTRESOURCE`. You can open an example Win32 App and inspect the code to find out more info

Comment: @Sourabh Singh Yadav Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I had to include "resource.h" file to make it work

Answer (score 1):

`LoadIcon` like most resource loading functions take a HINSTANCE/HMODULE parameter that identifies the .exe/.dll file where the resource resides and a string that identifies the name of a specific resource. In addition to using a string name, Windows also supports naming resources by a number < 65536. `MAKEINTRESOURCE` is a macro that just casts a number to a string.

The actual name you have to use is the same as the name you (or your IDE) used when you added the icon to your .rc file.

A common pattern is to store defines with the names in a resource.h file. If you are unsure what the name is, inspect your .rc file, it should contain a line like

```
ICON IDI_MYICON "theIcon.ico"
```

where `IDI_MYICON` is the define you can use with `MAKEINTRESOURCE`.